# How to export Visual Studio project to Qt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, export

I wonder how can I export a Visual Studio C++ project to Qt?

I am using openCV and OpenMP so I would like to know about setting these libraries in Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to myself.
Visual Studio is capable to export the current project to a make file so.
File>Export to make file should work.
(I got this info form microsoft msdn site. So, it should work)

Comment: You may want to add a link to the msdn article Not very helpful otherwise. :)

Comment: I think this is the link,
Even though I actually never tried, but I think it should work:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233950(VS.60).aspx