# Export Visual Studio project to Qt Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, sln-file

I would like to export my Visual Studio Project to a Qt project.

How to generate a `.pro` file from a Visual Studio Project? I installed the Qt Add-In but I don't find such option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to export visual studio project to qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622936/how-to-export-visual-studio-project-to-qt)

Comment: This answer is not clear... I do not find the tools to do it.

Comment: Have you installed the VS Qt plugin? You can download it from [Qt's official webpage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html#visual-studio-add-in).

Comment: Yes I have it. What should I do next ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Visual Studio Qt plugin installed (officially named Qt VS Tools, can be downloaded from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/index.html#)), just:

1. Open your solution.
2. Select any Qt-based project from your solution (or any file within that project).
3. Go to menu `Qt VS Tools > Create basic .pro File...`. If you are using an old version of the plugin, menu may be named `Qt5`.
4. Select the projects you want to export. Project tags (.pro options, only in newest plugin versions) are automatically extract from your current project, you can modify them if needed or do it later when the .pro is created.
5. Run `qmake` or open it from Qt Creator.

PS: depending on your VS and Qt versions you may need an older version of the plugin. I'm assuming Qt 5 here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ooh thanks. I did not see the "Create basic .pro file" because the option is grayed out.. Do you know what could be the reason ?

Comment: As indicated, you have to first select a Qt-based project in your solution (of course, you have to open the solution first).

Comment: Ooh ok, so I think my solution is not a QT based project.. I thought it will be possible to convert a non QT based project to a QT project !

Comment: You can, but it is a manual procedure, see this [answer here for Qt 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088315/how-to-convert-a-regular-win32-vc-vcproj-project-to-a-qt-project). I haven't found an answer for Qt 5, but you can create a new Qt project and then see the differences in the `.vcxproj` files.

Comment: @cbuchart Which project tag should be used?

Comment: @C.Binair I've update the answer to cover such new field, which was not available in the version of the plugin used 2.5 years ago ;)